# data.table and error handling using try statement

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to incorporate a bit of error handling in my R code.

Pseudo-code below:

---

```
foo = function(X,Y) {
...

return(ret.df);
}

DT = DT[,ret.df := foo(X,Y), by=key(DT)];
```

---

The aim is to check if for some combination of `X`,`Y` the function `foo` raises an error. If it does raise an error then I want to skip that record combination in the ultimate resultant data-frame. I have tried below without much luck:

---

```
    DT = DT[ ,  try(ret.df = : foo(X,y)); 
    if(not (class(ref.df) %in% "try-error') ) {
        return(ret.df);
    }, by = key(DT) ];
```

---

I can always try and write a wrapper around `foo` to do the error checking however am looking for a way to write the syntax directly in data.table call. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Conceptually, handling this type of error should be the responsibility of the function passed to data.table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a dummy function and data :

```
foo = function(X,Y) {
    if (any(Y==2)) stop("Y contains 2!")
    X*Y
}
DT = data.table(a=1:3, b=1:6)
DT
   a b
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
3: 3 3
4: 1 4
5: 2 5
6: 3 6
```

**Step by step :**

```
> DT[, c := foo(a,b), by=a ]
Error in foo(a, b) : Y contains 2!
```

Ok, that's by construction. Good.

Aside: notice column `c` was added, despite the error.

```
> DT
   a b  c
1: 1 1  1
2: 2 2 NA
3: 3 3 NA
4: 1 4  4
5: 2 5 NA
6: 3 6 NA
```

Only the first successful group was populated; it stopped at the second group. This is by design. At some point in the future we could add *transactions* to `data.table` internally, like SQL, so that if an error happened, any changes could be *rolled back*. Anyway, just something to be aware of.

To deal with the error you can use `{}`.

First attempt :

```
> DT[, c := {
    if (inherits(try(ans<-foo(a,b)),"try-error"))
        NA
    else
        ans
}, by=a]
Error in foo(a, b) : Y contains 2!
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c, { : 
  Type of RHS ('logical') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would
  impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of
  the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead
  of 1)
```

The error tells us what to do. Let's coerce the type of the RHS (`NA`) from `logical` to `integer`.

```
> DT[, c:= {
    if (inherits(try(ans<-foo(a,b)),"try-error"))
        NA_integer_
    else
        ans
}, by=a]
Error in foo(a, b) : Y contains 2!
```

Better, the long error has gone. But why still the error from `foo`? Let's look at `DT` just to check.

```
> DT
   a b  c
1: 1 1  1
2: 2 2 NA
3: 3 3  9
4: 1 4  4
5: 2 5 NA
6: 3 6 18
```

Oh, so it has worked. The 3rd group has run and values 9 and 18 appear in rows 3 and 6. Looking at `?try` reveals the `silent` argument.

```
> DT[, c:= {
    if (inherits(try(ans<-foo(a,b),silent=TRUE),"try-error"))
        NA_integer_
    else
        ans
}, by=a]
> # no errors
> DT
   a b  c
1: 1 1  1
2: 2 2 NA
3: 3 3  9
4: 1 4  4
5: 2 5 NA
6: 3 6 18
```

Comment: Matt - brilliant solution..thanks for such a detailed reply. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

There's a function from plyr that you might find useful here - it wraps up exactly what Matt did, but in a succinct and reusable way: `failwith()`.

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

foo = function(X,Y) {
    if (any(Y==2)) stop("Y contains 2!")
    X*Y
}
DT = data.table(a=1:3, b=1:6)
DT

DT[, c := failwith(NA_integer, foo)(a,b), by=a ]
```

`failwith` takes two arguments: a value to return on error, and a function to modify, `f`. It returns a new version of `f` that instead of throwing an error will return a default value.

The definition of `failwith` is pretty simple:

```
failwith <- function(default = NULL, f, quiet = FALSE) {
  f <- match.fun(f)
  function(...) {
    try_default(f(...), default, quiet = quiet)
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice one - similar in spirit with Try/Catch syntax of C++